# Return first non-null value after transformation in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I'd like to return the first non-null value after the transformation of a list of elements in Kotlin, so something like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun myFunction(): Any {
    val firstNonNullId = this.mapNotNull{ it.id }
        ?.first{ transform(id) != null }

    return transform(firstNonNullID)
}
```

What would be a better and more idiomatic way to write this function? I'd like to call upon `transform(it)` as few times as possible, and the transformation in question is also a `suspend` function.

**Edit:** The `asSequence()` solution gives an error when the `transform()` is a `suspend` function, as it must be called from a coroutine body. This happens even if the overall `myFunction()` is a suspend function. What should the solution be when the transformation is a suspend function?

Comment: If the transformation is a suspend function, you can only do this from within a coroutine. Isn't that also true with your code above? Do you need to transform every item in the collection, even though you aren't storing the transformed elements besides the first one?

Comment: if the transformation is a suspend function, and the overall function is also a suspend function, then it is fine. However, while the overall function is a suspend function, and the transformation is called from a sequence, it is no longer a part of the original coroutine body.

Comment: What about my other question? I think the sequence solution would skip transforming all elements after the first, even if it did work. Same as your code above. But you said "first non-value *after* the transformation".

Comment: I do not need to transform every item in the collection, which is the reason I used the `first` instead of for example calling `filterNotNull`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Kotlin 1.5, you can use [`firstNotNullOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-not-null-of.html) function or its [`...OrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-not-null-of-or-null.html) variant:

```
// returns the first non-null result of transform
this.firstNotNullOf { transform(it.id) }
```

`firstNotNullOf` throws an exception if no non-null result of the transformation is found, and `firstNotNullOfOrNull` returns null in this situation.

Both functions are inline, so it should be possible to call suspend functions in their lambda parameters when they are themselves invoked from a suspend function.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use Kotlin [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html):

```kotlin
this.asSequence()
    .mapNotNull { it.id }
    .mapNotNull { transform(it) }
    .first()
```

Since sequence evaluation is lazy, your transform function will only be called during the call to `.first()`, and it will not be called after the first non-null result is obtained.

Comment: Tried this solution, but in this case the transformation is a suspend function, so it gives an error - see edit!

Comment: It should work if you use `asFlow` instead of `asSequence`. Flow can be thought of as a suspending-capable version of a Sequence.